# How do I set Tasker to start a countdown timer for an alarm when I scan an nfc tag?

Tags: tasker

How do I set Tasker to start a countdown timer for an alarm when I scan an nfc tag?

I hear people talking about doing this, but not sure how to go about setting it up.  I can write and scan nfc tags with Locale NFC Plugin, it's the task that sets a time (based on a tag in the nfc tag) that I'm having a problem with.

How can I set up Tasker to countdown X minutes and have a sound/alert play when it reaches 00:00.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the "Start System Timer" action. Set it to the desired number of seconds and (optionally) check the box to show the UI. When the task is activated Google Clock will display the countdown and play the alarm sound when it reaches 0:00.